# Jquery overflow:hidden area get droppable

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I'm facing issue with drag and drop using jQuery

here the overflow hidden area is not working. when I drag and drop outside the drop area. its get hit and show a message that 'dropped!'

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable"> 
    <p>Drag me to my target</p> 
</div> 
<div class="dropcont">
      <div class="droppable"> 
          <p>Drop here</p> 
      </div> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .find( "p" )
                        .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    background: #DDD;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
}

#draggable { 
    background: #78BA91;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 

    float: left; 

}

.dropcont{
    left:200px;
     width: 150px; 
      height: 150px; 
    display:inline-block;
   overflow:hidden;

}

.droppable { 
    background: #6B7B95;
    width: 600px; 
    height: 600px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px; 


}
```

Please find the link below

http://jsfiddle.net/mL338128/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try bind droppable event to .dropcont instead of .droppable.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".dropcont" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thankyou for reply, inside the container (.dropcont ) it have multiple div (.droppable ) so the above code will not work for my situation.

Comment: @B.P Then you may want to add a empty sibling div.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `div` contain class `dropcont` because that prevent `droppable` to sense right aria.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="draggable"> 
    <p>Drag me to my target</p> 
</div> 

<div class="droppable"> 
    <p>Drop here</p> 
</div>
<div class="droppable"> 
    <p>Drop here</p> 
</div>
```

Find Solution http://jsfiddle.net/mL338128/3/